Iodine monochloride (I-Cl) bond cleavage issue
During an electrophilic addition of iodine monochloride $(\ce{ICl})$ with alkene, the $\ce{I-Cl}$ bond cleaves as $\ce{I+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$. Then $\ce{I+}$ attacks the double bond, and later $\ce{Cl-}$ attaches as well to form a dihaloalkane.
So, why does $\ce{I-Cl}$ cleave in such a way? Shouldn't it cleave as $\ce{I-}$ and $\ce{Cl+}$?
For example, in nucleophilic substitution reactions, $\ce{I-}$ acts as a better leaving group than $\ce{Cl-}$. Also, in aprotic solvent, $\ce{Cl-}$ is a better nucleophile. So I was expecting a similar behavior here also...
I know that electronegativity factor supports $\ce{I+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ type cleavage, so how to predict in such situations without experimental data?

The process is concerted - there's no separate I+.

But the mechanism given in Solomons and Fryhle page 347 shows the formation of a carbocation after addition of I+

I mean C=C substitutes Cl- creating cyclic iodonium cation. Not sure what's your comment about.

I mean, according to Solomons and Fryhle, the reaction proceeds through a carbocation mechanism, as in, a carbocation that can undergo rearrangement and stuff, after I+ attaches to the double bond. There is no mention of cyclic halonium intermediate.

Also, even if the reaction proceeds through a iodonium intermediate, my question still stands right? Why iodonium intermediate instead of chloronium?

"But we know that I- is more stable than Cl- " What is this supposed to mean? More stable with respect to (WRT) what? For instance if it is stability WRT oxidation iodide is much more easily oxidised  then chloride, just look at the electrode potentials. WRT what change is iodide more stable than chloride?

I mean, in many cases in organic chemistry, the formation of I- being preferred over the formation of Cl-.

For example, in nucleophilic substitution reactions, I- acts as a better leaving group than Cl-. Also, in aprotic solvent, Cl- is a better nucleophile. So I was expecting a similar behavior here also...

Hello everyone, sorry for wasting some of your time. I should have been more clear in asking my question. I have edited my question now...
